# Programmatically test access to a given path with FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Is it possible to programmatically test whether the current user is able to access a given path? This would be a path to a resource somewhere that I need to restrict access to, and it would be a resource which is being accessed via a handler rather than directly by its path.

For example, given these configuration settings:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login/" defaultUrl="~/private/" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
</authentication>

...

<location path="private">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="private/general">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="general" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Could we do something like this?:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAllowedToAccess("~/private/general/my-resource")
```

Which would return `true` for users within the 'general' role, and `false` for anyone else?

Note that the configuration settings are just an example - there could potentially be a lot more location definitions and roles etc., so testing using lots of `myPath.StartsWith("/private/")` statements isn't really a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never quite managed to figure this out, so I had to change the approach slightly.

This is assuming that the resource we're trying to get at is one that wouldn't normally be served by IIS - in my case, this is web forms user controls (.ascx), which I want to get via Ajax, rendered to a string, which can then be injected by JavaScript somewhere in the HTML.

I got rid of the handler, and instead made it so that any requests to these resources were made directly to the resource, but with a slightly modified .ascx.asmx extension. For example, `/private/general/my-resource.ascx.asmx`.

I then added a HTTP module (integrated pipeline mode):

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="MyResourceHttpModule" type="MyApp.Controls.MyResourceHttpModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

(or classic pipeline mode):

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="MyResourceHttpModule" type="MyApp.Controls.MyResourceHttpModule" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

And the related code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public class MyResourceHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        #region IHttpModule Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.AuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(OnAuthorizeRequest);
        }

        #endregion

        void OnAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = (HttpApplication)sender;

            if (application.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".ascx.asmx"))
            {
                application.Context.RewritePath("~/Services/MyResource.asmx/GetResource");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This module rewrites the requested URL to a web service (MyResource.asmx), which then strips off the extra extension we originally added, and finally serves the file we're trying to get to (in this case, a web forms user control):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace MyApp.Services
{
    [ScriptService]
    public class MyResource : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public object GetResource()
        {
            var controlPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

            if (Paths.ApplicationPath != "" && controlPath.StartsWith(Paths.ApplicationPath)) controlPath = '~' + controlPath.Substring(Paths.ApplicationPath.Length);
            if (controlPath.EndsWith(".asmx")) controlPath = controlPath.Substring(0, controlPath.Length - 5);

            using (var myUserControl = (MyApp.Controls.MyUserControl)(new Page()).LoadControl(controlPath))
            {
                myUserControl.DataBind();

                return myUserControl.RenderToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This uses this RenderToString extension method):

```
public static string RenderToString(this System.Web.UI.Control control)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
    {
        using (var htmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            control.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This all works because forms authentication runs through the authorization rules set in web.config before allowing the request, so we know that by the time it reaches our HTTP module it's OK to serve the requested file because the current user must have permission to access the path.